# Django display images in model form formset on validation error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm building an app where users can create projects; within each project, they can create 'locations', to which photos can be associated. Photo is a generic content model which can be associated with many other types of models. In this case the photos have already been uploaded and are associated to the project. The user can choose them to be associated with the location via a javascript modal window, then add a 'note' to them.

Originally I built this entirely manually and accessed the photos in the view via request.POST; however I had some trouble with the text values from the notes and so decided it would be easier/better to do it properly and build an actual model formset.

**The photos are displayed in the template by accessing the .instance attribute of the form**

This is working fine - I can add the photos and notes, and also remove them from a location if they have previously been added. 
The problem is, however - that if the form has any validation errors and the user is returned to the template to deal with them, the image itself is not shown. This seems to be because the form does not have an instance attribute attached to it. The photo is displayed without any problem via the tag `<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ photo.instance.photo.small.url }}">`(using easy thumbnails) on the photos that are already saved to the location, but not for those that have just been added/edited.

My question is - how can I display the nice pretty picture in this situation?

Here's my model form:

```
class PhotoDisplayForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Photo
    fields = {'id', 'note', }
    widgets = {
        'note': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3}),
        'photo': HiddenInput(),
        'id': HiddenInput(),
    }
```

views.py

```
def location_form(request, project_id, location_id=None):
project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
photos_formset = []

if location_id is None:  #creates unbound forms
    locPhotoFS = formset_factory(PhotoDisplayForm, max_num=0, can_delete=True)
    photos_formset = locPhotoFS(prefix='loc_photos')

    use_type = 'create' #this variable is passed to the template to display appropriate text
    location_form = QuadratForm(request.POST or None, project_id=project_id)

else:   ### edit an existing form  ####
    use_type = 'edit'
    location = get_object_or_404(Location, pk=location_id)
    location_form = QuadratForm(request.POST or None, project_id=project_id)

    location_photos = Photo.objects.filter(location = location)
    locPhotoFS = modelformset_factory(Photo, PhotoDisplayForm, max_num=0,  can_delete=True)
    photos_formset = locPhotoFS(queryset = location_photos, prefix='loc_photos')            

if request.method == 'POST': 
    photos_formset = locPhotoFS(request.POST, prefix='loc_photos')

    if location_form.is_valid() and photos_formset.is_valid():
        location_instance = location_form.save(commit=False)
        location_instance.project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
        location_instance.save()

        for form in photos_formset:
            p = form.cleaned_data['id']
            if form.cleaned_data['DELETE']:
                p.content_object = project #reassociate the photo with the project
                p.save()
            else:   
                p.content_object = location_instance
                p.note = form.cleaned_data['note'].strip()
                print p.note
                p.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('core.views.location', args=(project_id, location_instance.id)))
    else:
        print 'there are errors'
context = {'location_type': location_type, 'use_type': use_type,'location_form': location_form,'project_photos': project.photos.all()}
if photos_formset:
    context['photos_formset'] = photos_formset
return render(request, 'location_form.html', context)
```

Template

```
{% if photos_formset %}
    {% if location_form.non_field_errors %}{{ location_form.non_field_errors }}{% endif %}
    {{ photos_formset.management_form }} 
    {% for photo in photos_formset %}
    {% if photo.non_field_errors %}{{ photo.non_field_errors }}{% endif %}
    <div class="photo-details original" id="{{photo.instance.id}}_photo-details">
        <button type="button" photo="{{photo.instance.id}}" class="close pull-right photo-delete" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div class="photo-notes">{{ photo.note.label_tag }}{{ photo.note|attr:"class:photo_notes_input" }}{{ photo.errors }}</div>
    {{ photo.id }}
    {{ photo.DELETE|attr:"class:delete-photo" }}
    <div class="thumbnail-caption">
    <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ photo.instance.photo.small.url }}">
    <br>{{ photo.instance.title }}
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Here's the photo model itself, if that's useful:

```
class Photo(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    photo = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to=imagePath)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    note = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a (somewhat hacky) solution.
Because I already have a queryset called project_photos which is being passed to the template (this creates the javascript modal list where photos can be selected to add to the location), I simply loop through these in the template and find one where the id matches (the variable photo is the current form within the formset loop):

```
    <div class="thumbnail-caption">
        {% if photo.instance.title %}
        <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ photo.instance.photo.small.url }}">
        <br>{{ photo.instance.title }}
        {% else %}
            {% with p=photo.id.value %}
                {% for pp in project_photos %}
                    {% ifequal p|stringformat:"s" pp.id|stringformat:"s" %}
                        <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ pp.photo.small.url }}">
                        <br>{{ pp.title }}
                    {% endifequal %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endwith %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

It was necessary to use the stringformat template filter - that got me stuck for a while.

This is not a perfect solution - because those photos are still displaying in the original javascript window (obviously I could work around that) - and also the template has to loop through a potentially large list of objects for each one which could slow things down.

Any suggestions for improvement gratefully accepted.